# Ban local loop-back traffic with exception on a port on Ubuntu

Tags: iptables

I would like to ban all the local loop-back traffic on my Ubuntu computer, with the exception that loop-back traffic to or from port 2947 (gpsd service port) should be allowed. How do I achieve this?

The command I used to ban loop-back traffic are:

`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j DROP`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j DROP`

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 2947 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --sport 2947 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j DROP
```

(But remember: it will probably cause a bunch of *mystical* errors)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you may guess, I want to ban local traffic and get the GPS coordinates at the same time. I tried your answer, all the loopback traffic are dropped, but I cannot obtain the coordinates as well.